# How do I Install version 2.5.1 of RabbitMQ using Homebrew?

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, homebrew

I'm in a situation where I absolutely must use the specific version 2.5.1 of RabbitMQ (or any version 2.5.x should do really) and I can't find how to install it via Homebrew anywhere, can anyone provide good instructions as to how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check whether version you need exists in homebrew

`$ brew versions rabbitmq`

Mine shows (... - skipped for readability):

```
...
2.5.1    git checkout 3630e1b Library/Formula/rabbitmq.rb
...
```

Then just checkout version you want (in your case 2.5.1):

`git checkout 3630e1b Library/Formula/rabbitmq.rb`

And finally install rabbitmq formula:

`brew install rabbitmq`